# Corrupt Photos in Photos_Private.photoslibrary

Tags: macos, filesystem, photos.app, file-transfer

When I try to open a photo in Photos_Private.photoslibrary, its corrupted. However, if I select Show Package Contents and open the Originals folder, everything is fine. So the question is, where do I need to copy the folder Originals to, to be able to view the images in Photos?

Comment: I might be experiencing a similar issue. Have a look at my post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416295/photos-library-shows-blanks-after-updating-the-library. Is your problem the same?

Comment: the first part sounds like you’re trying to open an image some way other than Photos.  Need clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Open Photos.app

Select the photos you’re interested in.

Menu-select Export, submenu export originals

Put them anywhere you want.

Edit: Having been alerted that I haven’t answered the question at the end, I decided to not delete this as it may be useful to someone else.

Comment: While this may work to get the original to some other place that's not an answer to the question. The OP asked how to view those pictures in the photos app again.

Comment: True.  I misunderstood the last sentence.

Comment: To clarify for WGroleau, the issue happens when trying to open jpg files directly in Photos app. Strangely enough, when going directly to the Originals folder, the jpg images open normally in Photos app.